# OkHTTP3 not working for specific ZipCode Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

When I try this zipCode: `1053 GB`, the API call works accordingly. `results` contains `geometry` with the correct `lat` and `lng`.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1053gb%2BNederland&components=country%3ANL&key=MY_SECRET_KEY
```

When I try `3221 as` it only works in chrome webbrowser and not using OkHTTP3:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3221as%2BNederland&key=MY_SECRET_KEY
```

Here is the code:

```
 class GoogleApiService(appApplication: AppApplication) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var googleApi: GoogleApi

    fun findLocation(zipCode: String): ZipCodeLocation {

        val responseCall = googleApi.getGeocode("$zipCode+Nederland", "country:NL", "SECRET_KEY")
        val execute = responseCall.execute()

        if (execute.isSuccessful) {
            val body = execute.body()
            if (body?.results?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
            // is empty for 3221 as
            }
        }
    }
}

interface GoogleApi {

    @GET("/maps/api/geocode/json")
    fun getGeocode(@Query("address") address: String, @Query("components") components: String, @Query("key") key: String): Call<GeoCodeResponse>
}

class GeoCodeResponse {
    @Keep
    @Json(name = "results")
    var results: List<GeoCodeResult>? = null
}

class GeoCodeResult {
    @Keep
    @Json(name = "geometry")
    var geometry: GeoGeometry? = null
}

class GeoGeometry {
    @Keep
    @Json(name = "location")
    var location: GeoLocation? = null
}

class GeoLocation {

    @Keep
    @Json(name = "lat")
    var lat: Double = 0.toDouble()

    @Keep
    @Json(name = "lng")
    var lng: Double = 0.toDouble()
}
```

the build.gradle:

```
ext {
    retrofit = '2.3.0'
    okhttp = '4.1.0'
}

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp"
```

Here are the Charles requests, first one via the Android App, second via Chrome browser on a Mac.

[image]

Working on Chrome, Mac:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've added the same headers as the Chrome request and then it worked:

```
@Headers(
        "User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36",
        "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1",
        "accept-language: nl,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,it;q=0.5",
        "sec-fetch-site: none",
        "sec-fetch-mode: navigate"
)
@GET("/maps/api/geocode/json")
fun getGeocode(@Query("address") address: String, @Query("components") components: String, @Query("key") key: String): Call<GeoCodeResponse>
```